# No se visualiza el contenido del componente de vue, laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Inicie un proyecto de laravel y vue con autenticacion de usuarios y registro y modifique el codigo de https://www.nigmacode.com/laravel/SPA-con-Laravel-y-Vuejs para adaptar las vistas de inicio de sesion y registro de usuarios para tener algo paracido pero con las vistas de auth de laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al iniciar sesion no se muestra el componente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

vista app.blade en donde dependiendo el rol del usuario se le mostrara las opciones que tenga disponible

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!-- Navbar app -->
    <div class="w3-top"> <!-- class="w3-top app -->
        <div class="w3-bar w3-red w3-card w3-left-align w3-large"> <!-- class="w3-bar app -->
            @guest
                <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Iniciar Sesión</a>
                @if (Route::has('register'))
                <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Registrarse app</a> 
                @endif
                @else
                    @if(Auth::check())
                        @if (Auth::user()->rol == 1)
                            @include('appAdministrador')
                        @else
                            @include('appUsuario')
                        @endif
                    @endif
            @endguest
        </div> <!-- fin class=w3-bar app -->
    </div><!-- fin class="w3-top"> app -->
    <div>
        @yield('content') <!---- llama al login o formulario de registro------>
    </div>
</div><!-- fin div="app" -- app -->
```

vista appAdministrador.blade con las opciones que tiene disponible por el rol

```
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white w3-large w3-red" 
        href="javascript:void(0);" 
        onclick="myFunction()" 
        title="Toggle Navigation Menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>

    <a href="#" 
        @click="menu=0" 
        class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hover-white" 
        v-bind:class="{ 'w3-white': menu==0}">
        admin page
    </a>

    <a href="#" 
        @click="menu=1" 
        class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white" 
        v-bind:class="{ 'w3-white': menu==1}">
        Sobre nosotros
    </a>

    <a href="#" 
        @click="menu=2" 
        class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white" 
        v-bind:class="{ 'w3-white': menu==2}">
        Contacto
    </a> 


    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large"> {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span></a>

    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="event.preventDefault();
             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            {{ __('Cerrar Session') }}

    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
    </form>

    </div>

    <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
    <div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-white w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-large">
        <a href="#" @click="menu=0" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Adminxxx page</a>
        <a href="#" @click="menu=1" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Sobre nosotros</a>
        <a href="#" @click="menu=2" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">Contacto</a>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!--Contenido dinamico que irá cambiando sin refrescar la pagina-->
    <div>
        @yield('contenidoAdmin')
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="w3-container w3-padding-64 w3-center w3-opacity">
        <div class="w3-xlarge w3-padding-32">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram w3-hover-opacity"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity"></i>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script>
    // Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
        if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
            x.className += " w3-show";
        } else {
            x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        }
    }
</script>
```

contenidoAdmin.blade

```
@extends('appAdministrador')

@section('contenidoAdmin')
  <template v-if="menu==0">
     <landing-page></landing-page>
  </template>
  <template v-if="menu==1">
     <contact-page></contact-page>
  </template>
  <template v-if="menu==2">
     <about-page></about-page>
  </template>

 @endsection
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('landing-page', require('./components/Landing.vue').default);
Vue.component('contact-page', require('./components/Contact.vue').default);
Vue.component('about-page', require('./components/About.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data:{
    menu:0,
},
methods: {
    changePage(menu){
        this.menu = menu;
    }
},
});
```

Comment: Si ves el código de fuente en el navegador y abres `app.js`, ¿Éste se encuentra actualizado?

Comment: Consulta en la consola del navegador y agrega en caso de ser necesario si aparece algún error

Comment: @Jonathan Orta a que se refiere si se encuentra actualizado el app.js?

Comment: @Aprendiz no, en la consola no obtengo ningún error

Comment: ¿Compilaste con `npm run dev`?

Comment: @Aprendiz si ya lo use, y siempre tengo corriendo el comando `npm run watch`.y no logro visualizar los componentes

Comment: En ocasiones el navegador, como es mi caso Chrome, debo abrir el archivo app.js y recargarlo con `Ctrl + R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues ya lo solucione, no como queria pero funciona

En la vista appAdministrador.blade tenia lo siguiente en donde buscaba la sección establecida para el admin

```
<div>
    @yield('contenidoAdmin')
</div>
```

Ahora llamo a los componentes directamente desde la vista appAdministrador.blade y funca a la perfección xd

```
 <div>
    <template v-if="menu==0">
       <landing-page></landing-page>
    </template>
    <template v-if="menu==1">
        <contact-page></contact-page>
    </template>
    <template v-if="menu==2">
        <about-page></about-page>
    </template>
 </div>
```

Comment: De ser esta la solución por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada, así el resto nos esteramos de la solución

Comment: @Aprendiz, ok listo.. pero me sale eso **Puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta en 2 días**  .. tocara esperar